# Retirar "disabled" com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, funções, javascript-eventos

Boa noite. Eu queria retirar o atributo disabled de uma tag quando certa condição for cumprida, mas não encontrei nenhuma ideia de como fazer isso. Abaixo o HTML:

```
Escreva aqui: <input type="text" id="text1" autofocus><br> <!--input livre-->
Depois aqui: <input type="text" id="text2" disabled> <!--deveria ficar livre depois que enviar o valor do input#text1-->
```

Agora o JavaScript:

```
const t = document.querySelector("#text1")
t.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key == 13) {     //quando a tecla enter é apertada a função abaixo acontece
    //aqui deveria entrar a função de tirar o disabled do input#text2 
}});
```

Se alguém puder, por favor, me ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para retirar o atributo `disabled` basta usar o método [`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) de `Element`. Este recebe uma `string` indicando o nome do atributo a remover, e não gera erro mesmo se o atributo não existir.

A utilização no seu exemplo ficaria:

```
document.querySelector("#text2").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Veja a funcionar:

```js
const t = document.querySelector("#text1")
t.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key == 13) {
      document.querySelector("#text2").removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
Escreva aqui: <input type="text" id="text1" autofocus><br> <!--input livre-->
Depois aqui: <input type="text" id="text2" disabled> <!--deveria ficar livre depois que enviar o valor do input#text1-->
```

Answer (score 3):

Basta setar o atributo `disabled` para false.

```
const t = document.querySelector("#text1")
t.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
if (key == 13) {     //quando a tecla enter é apertada a função abaixo acontece
    document.getElementById("text2").disabled = false; 
}});
```

Comment: Já tentei fazer isso e não funcionou ainda.

Comment: Ele está entrando dentro do `if(key == 13)` ? Se tiver como você testar e falar pra nós.

Comment: Está sim, igual a como comentou.

Comment: Tenta dar um `console.log(document.getElementById("text2"))` pra ver se ele tá conseguindo pegar o elemento.

Answer (score 1):

E se formos além da necessidade simples?

Uma sugestão (de várias) seria:

- Quando houver o disparo do **Enter** no <input> atual, passamos para o próximo e "desativa" o `disabled`, caso tenha;
- Quando não houver um próximo, volta ao primeiro;
- Sem necessidade de adicionar um identificador em cada <input>.

```js
//usando es6
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('div input') //pega todos os 'inputs' dentro de 'div'

    inputs.forEach((input, index) => {

        input.dataset.index = index // attr 'data-index'
        input.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{
            let _this = e.target
            let _index = parseInt(_this.dataset.index, 10) //converte string em numero
            let keycode = e.keyCode || e.which
            if(keycode === 13) { //is Enter
                let nextSibling = inputs[_index+1]
                if(nextSibling !== undefined) {
                    nextSibling.disabled = false //remove o disabled
                } else nextSibling = inputs[0] // volta para o primeiro input

                nextSibling.focus() // autofoco
                // nextSibling.select() // caso precise fazer selecionar todo o valor
            }

        })

    })
```

```css
input{margin-bottom:5px}
```

```html
    <div>
        a: <input type="text" autofocus><br>
        b: <input type="text" disabled><br>
        c: <input type="text" disabled><br>
        d: <input type="text" disabled><br>
        e: <input type="text" disabled><br>
        [...]
    </div>
```

obs: o js tem que estar no final de todo o código. -antes do fechamento  </body> -